# mouseleave all like wrapAll

Tags: jquery, mouseleave

It's possible to make a mouseleave function not for each element but for all without a wrap element like [wrapAll](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) can do, something like a mouseleaveAll ?

```
 $('.map').on({
 mouseenter: function(){
// stuff
},
mouseleaveAll: function(){ // don't try this at home ! 
//stuff
}
```

Comment: you would need to create a jquery plugin (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) and possibly pass in the wrap selector to exclude elements you don't want to give the mouse leave event to

Comment: Elements are in position absolute, not easy to have an "hover" wrap.

Comment: Sorry for my last comment, it's work with a warp (with a 0 width dimension)!